# Force python to be globally linked to /usr/bin/python3 on macOS (non-alias)

Tags: macos, python, path

Calling `python` from any terminal or when an other process tries to spawn it, causes "Install Command Line Tools" popup. After installation it still does the same.

- Linking `/usr/bin/python3` to `/usr/local/bin/python` does not help (even though `which` says correctly)
- Changing `PATH` to point to a new location with this link (like `~/.local/bin`) doesn't help either
- `alias` wouldn't work - this is needed for another process to spawn `python` (hardcoded into binary)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it actually helped to look at these instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704099).

Here are the steps:

1. get location of developer tools: `xcode-select -p`. For me this was at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
2. create link to python3:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python`

After that a call to `python` seemed to end up at `python3`, and the install developer tools notification did not appear again.